# Timer runs automatically on a MsgBox vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a validation where the user is able to choose between 2 different results from a MsgBox and if no one were selected it will close. But the method that I got is not working.

This is the code that I am actually using to make this validation:

```
    Private Sub watcher_idle(sender As Object) Handles watcher.Idle
        Dim result = MessageBox.Show("The application will close because a lot of time off.", "Are you sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)

        If result = DialogResult.Yes Then
            End
        ElseIf result = DialogResult.No Then

        ElseIf Timer4.Interval = 3000 Then
            Timer4.Start()
            End
        End If
    End Sub
```

If user select Yes the application will close, if user select no it doesn't do anything and if the user does not select anything for 3 secs or something like that the application will close automatically. But this last  step is not making anything. Does not work.

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: When opening a message box you are opening a modal window which blocks execution for the entire thread (in this case the UI thread). Your timer won't be able to continue until you've closed the message box. You also have the problem that you're checking if the `Interval` property is 3000 ms (3 seconds). That property won't change when the timer ticks, it only tells the timer _how often to tick_. Any modifications to it are done by you or your code.

Comment: Also `End` is probably not the best to use as it stops execution immediately. You should use `Application.Exit()` instead as that will release resources and close message pumps correctly before closing.

Comment: So, what do you suggest if I want to make this work with a timer? If user does not select any of the options from MessageBox it will close automatically @VisualVincent

Comment: Create your own custom MessageBox and put your timer logic in it.

Comment: From your code structure, I guess you're not really familiar with timers, [Here is a link on how to use it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Mark's solution would be it. Possibly you can use a thread but that's a bit more complicated.